# Async Command and AWK for Changing files in AWS S3

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-s3, awk

I would like to rename pdf files I have in an AWS S3 bucket, changing their names from some sort of numbers we use, into UUIDs we have in a PostgreSQL table.

Currently, I'm trying to do it like this:

```bash
export PGPASSWORD="<my_password>"

echo "SELECT id, number FROM mytable"                    \
  | psql -h <local-docker-ip> -p <docker-port> -U <user> \
  | head -n -2                                           \ # this is only for eliminating extra text
  | awk 'NR > 2 { aws s3 --profile Admin-Profile mv "s3://<bucket>/documents/" $3 ".pdf" " " "s3://<bucket>/documents/" $1 ".pdf" }'
```

The string concatenation I'm using into `awk` is probably wrong, but I don't know how to work around it. Also, if anyone knows a better way of doing this, I'm open to suggestions, of course.

Comment: perhaps update the question with the complete output from the `psql/SELECT` (ie, the input) and the desired `aws` calls (ie, the expected result); if you're just swapping a number for a uuid then chances are the `awk` code can be replaced with a simple `bash/while` loop, but will need to see the actual `psql/SELECT` output